# Generating SVG files in browser now that data URLs seem to be deprecated?

Tags: javascript, url, svg, single-page-application

I'm trying to create an in-browser Single Page App that generates SVG files.

However, according to : https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2017/data-url-navigations-on-top-level-window-will-now-be-blocked/ Firefox, at least, is blocking data: urls as a security risk.

Is there still a way to make such an app. generate SVGs?

Comment: Note that you can still generate SVGs, just not be able to open them in a top-level window. "Meanwhile, these operations will not be affected: [...] A page uses a data URL for an image or other assets; A page triggers a data file download"

Comment: So how do I tell it not to use a top level window? I'm generating the SVG and adding it to the URL with "data:image/svg+xml;" as the mime-type. But can I do anything to the anchor to tell it "not in the top level window"?

Comment: Why do you need your SVG files to be served as dataURLs exactly? To allow it to be downloaded on user's disk?

Comment: Also, what is the scenario? You generate them in order... for them to be displayed on the current page? ... to be displayed in a separate page? ... to be downloaded by the user?

Comment: Yes to be downloaded by the user. It's a diagram creating application that lives entirely in the browser. There's no server involved.

Comment: Then use `<a download="filename.svg" href="data:image/svg+xml...` This use is explicitly white-listed. An other alternative in case you do produce huge files, would be to produce a  Blob  from the markup and set the href of this anchor to a blobURI.

Comment: Ah ... thanks @kaiido I didn't know about that ... oddly enough it seems to work but the downloaded file is missing some characters at the beginning. Is there some size limit?

Comment: There is a size limit, only on Chrome, and it wouldn't remove characters, just fail. So you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I made a separate question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712827/dataurl-seems-to-lose-the-beginning 

If I literally paste that download link into a file that contains nothing but an html and a body tag, I get the same effect. It downloads, but truncates off the front. Very weird

Comment: OK ... I got this working with Blobs ... cheers @Kaiido